# efficient parallel algorithm to update traversal costs for all simple paths in a weighted, directed graph

Tags: parallel-processing, gpgpu, graph-databases, graph-traversal, blazegraph

I'm working with relatively small directed graphs (~10 nodes) which each have ~10,000 simple paths and cycles.  I'd like to maintain a sorted list of aggregate costs to traverse all of these simple paths and cycles. My edges have several different weights, but the aggregation functions are commutative/associative (e.g. sums and products) for all of them.

Right now, I’m using rethinkdb (a nosql database) and python. I’m precomputing all possible simple paths, storing them in a hash map, and just brute force recalculating traversal costs them every time an edge weight is updated. My hash map points a given edge (whose weight has just been updated) to all the simple paths and cycles that it is a part of. Then I go and recalculate traversal costs for each of those.

Well, I'm finding that this is very slow and doesn’t scale!  I'm aware that this is a *hard problem*, but was hoping that it was doable for my relatively small graphs.

One inefficiency in my original approach seemed to be in the wasteful redundant computation of every single path, even though some are aggregates of each other. For example, the cost of A→B→C→D→E is a composition of A→B→C and C→D→E. So why not compute them smartly? I came up with a way of doing this and it just didn’t seem to help one single bit, which made me think I really needed to take a step back.

So I went on the internet and did some searching, and stumbled on this very helpful article:
https://blog.blazegraph.com/?p=628 . It says:

> The big graph anti-pattern is “Throw everything into a big graph and
>   then using the same tools that gave us horizontal scaling for other
>   problems: map/reduce and key-value stores.”

It strikes me that this is exactly what I’ve been doing (wrong).

And it seems like the GPU is the right solution to the memory bandwidth problem mentioned in the article...  except that I'm not sure how to approach this problem in parallel.

**Questions:**

1. how to approach this problem in parallel?  Is gather-apply-scatter the right direction?  Where has this been done before?
2. how might I effectively optimize the current approach without going parallel?

**For reference, here is a sketch of my current algorithm:**

1. enumerate all simple paths and cycles in my graph
2. keep a dictionary of edges and their weights.  e.g., if `('A','B')`
   is an the edge from node `A` to node `B`,

   ```
   edges_weights[('A','B')] # -> {'x': 1.3, 'y': 32, 'z': 0.231232}
   ```
3. keep a dictionary of all simple paths and cycles that each edge is involved in, e.g.:

   ```
   paths_containing_edges[('A','B')] 
   # ->
   # [
   #      (('A','B'), ('B','C')), 
   #      (('A','B'), ('B','C'), ('C','D')), 
   #      (('A','B'), ('B','C'), ('C','A')), 
   #      ... 
   #      (('A','B'), ('B','C'), ('C','D'), ('D','A'))
   # ]
   ```
4. Also, initialize a dictionary of paths and their costs:

   ```
   paths_costs = {
           (('A','B'), ('B','C')): {'x': ..., 'y': ..., 'z': ...}
   }
   ```
5. When an edge is updated:

   i. update its weights in `edges_weights`

   ii. lookup all simple paths containing this edge and update them:

   ```
   fn = lambda p,q: p+q # the cost aggregation function        
   weight_keys = ['x','y','z']
   for path in paths_containing_edges[updated_edge]:
     # path is a tuple of edge tuples, i.e. (('A','B'),('B','C'),('C','D'))
     for w in weight_keys:
       paths_costs[path][w] = reduce(fn,[edges_weights[e][w] for e in path])
   ```

Clearly there are a lot of nested loops and lookups happening...  But I'm struggling to see how I could do things differently.

Comment: you also might try experimenting with apache tinkerpop/gremlin. A gremlin query might be able to give you more insight and you could try different algorithms before trying to optimize. Could you supply an example in one of the formats that tinkerpop can read / write?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether I understood your problem right. Still i'll have a try:

If you have n nodes than there are max (n*n-n)/2 edges between your nodes.

If n is 10 that means there are 50 possible edges.

The max path length for 10 nodes is 10 before you get a cycle.
A simple array of your edges should make sure that you can access the weigh information of your edges.
So if e.g. there is a path A->B->C->D->E->G->H->I->J

You will have to sum up (A->B) (B->C) (D->E) (E->F) (E->G) (H-I) (I->J)
Now the question is: what is quicker - the look up cost to find the solution for a subsum of this or simply adding over the array-pointers and keeping those pointers? Keeping 10.000 pointers and summing the numbers is something that should be really fast. Especially if you keep your weights as numbers that the CPU can handle well. I assume they are int, long and not float or double and even if with a 64 bit cpu this should be no issue.

Given your small numbers I would try to simply create a most efficient calculation using an adequate programming language like C / Assembler that will bring down the CPU cycles for the calculation. My gut feeling is that this will be quicker than finding an efficient algorithm (but only for small numbers of n - i wonder where the cutover point would be ...)

Comment: Thank you for this response.  Moving to a compiled language feels like really good advice.  at the very least, it would give me an idea of what's actually going on in memory.  Maybe this is a good opportunity to learn Rust.

I recently saw a video of python 3 running on a 486 in 2018:  https://youtu.be/4qSziR6sD8Q?t=1219

It takes 13 seconds to fire up python and print "Hello, world"!  The magic comes at a cost.